# Overload operator in c++

Tags: c++

I want to overload the "=" operator that will works on this code:

```
void toArr(AVLNode<Student> student, Student* studentArr){
    int studentID = student.data; //This is where I want to use that operator
    ....
}

int operator=(int number, const Student& student){ //Error: 'int operator=(int, const Student&)' must be a nonstatic member function
    Student tmp = student;
    return (tmp.getID());
}
```

`tmp.getID()` is an `int`. 
Is this even possible?

FYI I search for the same problem but didn't find one with 2 arguments..

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want? show us a use case for this operator

Comment: I think what you’re looking for is a conversion – it might be `operator int() const { return this->getID(); }`?

Comment: at the "void" function you can see the use. I want to assign the "tmp.getID()" into "studentID"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a cast operator in your class `Student` to type `int`:

```
class Student
{
public:

    int id;
    int getID() const { return id; }

    operator int() const
    {
       return getID();
    }
};

Student student;
int id = student;
```